# Specific Comparer For Distinct

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq, c#-4.0, distinct

I have to implement specific comparer for  Distinct :

```
public class MyModuleComparer : IEqualityComparer<GenDictionnaireMenu>
{
    

    public bool Equals(GenDictionnaireMenu x, GenDictionnaireMenu y)
    {
        //Check whether the compared objects reference the same data. 
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;

        //Check whether any of the compared objects is null. 
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, null) || Object.ReferenceEquals(y, null))
            return false;

        return x.LibelleModule == y.LibelleModule;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(GenDictionnaireMenu obj)
    {
        return obj == null ? 0 : (int)obj.CodeDictionnaireMenu;
    }
}
```

and I use it when I call Distinct like this :

```
Dim list = ListDictionnaire.Distinct(New MyModuleComparer()).ToList
```

the problem is that I have the same object having the same LibelleModule in "list" like this :

> object1 = code : 1, LibelleModule : "Gestion administrative" , LIBELLE_SOUS_MODULE1: "Congé"
>
> object2 = code : 2, LibelleModule : "Gestion administrative" , LIBELLE_SOUS_MODULE1: "Congé"
>
> object3 = code : 3, LibelleModule : "Gestion administrative" , LIBELLE_SOUS_MODULE1: "Gestion carrière"

please any suggestions!

Comment: Why do you use LibelleModule in Equals and CodeDictionnaireMenu in GetHashCode ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must provide a different `GetHashCode` implementation.

`Distinct()` first calls the light `GetHashCode` function, and only calls `Equals` if there is a collision, i.e. if `GetHashCode` produces the same result for two instances of `GenDictionnaireMenu`.

Here is the `GetHashCode` definition:

> Two objects that are equal return hash codes that are equal. However,
>   the reverse is not true: equal hash codes do not imply object
>   equality.

That's why `Equals` is never called (`CodeDictionnaireMenu` is different for all your instances), and that's why two of your instances are considered to be identical.

EDIT:

Well it's a bit complicated actually. See the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) doc for all the details.

One of the main rule is:

> If two objects compare as equal, the GetHashCode method for each
>   object must return the same value. However, if two objects do not
>   compare as equal, the GetHashCode methods for the two objects do not
>   have to return different values.

So if your items compare as equal when having the same `LibelleModule` property, then their hash code should be identical. In your case the hash code is always different even if `LibelleModule` is the same.

So, one possible hash code could be:

```
public int GetHashCode(GenDictionnaireMenu obj)
{
    return obj.LibelleModule != null ? obj.LibelleModule.GetHashCode() : 0;
}
```

Comment: yes,i see that code inside Equalsis never exectuted, but i dont understand the rule of GetHashCode !! can you give an indication on what should be inside GetHashCode !